How to run sql script in plsql by @'path?
I would like to run two scripts test1.sql and test2.sql one after the other which look like that:
test_1:
select * from hr fetch first 10 rows only;
test_2:
select * from sys fetch first 10 rows only;
in PL/SQL code.
In the table PROCEDURE_NAMES there are two columns: pr_index and script names. It looks like that:
column_name    data_type   nullable

pr_index            integer        no
script_name      varchar2(100)     yes
Data:
pr_index | script_name
1        | test1.sql
2        | test2.sql
I've tried like that:
declare
    v_path varchar2(15) := 'C:\UserData\HP';
    v_name_proc varchar2(100);
    v_path_and_name_proc := varchar2(100);
begin
    for i in 1..2 loop
    select script_name
    into v_name_proc
    from procedure_names
    where pr_index = i;

    v_path_and_name := v_path || v_name_proc;  
    @v_path_and_name;

   end loop;
end;

but I've got error ORA-06550 in 13 line
PLS-00103: pls-00103 encountered the symbol @ when expecting one of the following:
( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null pragma rise return select update while with    << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array
)
I have tried change 13 line to:
@ || v_path_and_name;
exec @v_path_and_name;
execute immediate @v_path_and_name;
but it doesn't work :(
How should I change it?
I need to run both scripts one after the other.

The "@" is a sqlplus command. pl/sql does not know about it. This question is a duplicate of yours.

What's the best way to write it differently? I would like to run sql files one by one in plsql

as I said, pl/sql cannot run client side scripts. Check my answer for a possible solution and let me know how it goes

pl/sql cannot run client side scripts. It's executed on the server. You can however execute an anonymous block to set a variable and reuse that variable in sqlplus. Make it a 2 step process. (1) Generate a generic script that points to your script (2) run that generic script.
18c>create table t_script (script VARCHAR2(100));

Table T_SCRIPT created.

18c>insert into t_script(script) values ('script1.sql');

1 row inserted.


script1.sql contains
select 'path1' as path,'script1' as script from dual;

first script:
variable l_path varchar2(100);
begin
:l_path := 'path1';
end;
/
set head off
spool tmp_script.sql
select '@'||:l_path||'\'||script from t_script;
spool off

Then run the generated script:
18c>@tmp_script.sql

path1 script1


afaik you cannot do this in a single process - others might know how to do that.
